# MyBatis - Mapping tree data-structure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

How can I map table `id | parent_id | name` to my pojo class:

```
public class Node {
  private Integer id;
  private Integer parentId;
  private String name;
  private List<Node> children;
  //getters and setters
}
```

I want to get list of root nodes (parent_id=null) with filled children list. No restriction in tree depth. I am thinking of something like:

```
<resultMap id="nodeResult" type="Node">
  <id property="id" column="id"/>
  <result property="parentId" column="parent_id"/>
  <result property="name" column="name"/>
  <collection property="children" resultMap="nodeResult"/>
</resultMap>
<select id="selectNode" resultMap="nodeResult">
  SELECT * FROM NODE
</select>
```

I don't know where to put restriction for children list: id=parentId. I don't want to use nested select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be a way to get an arbitrarly deep tree to populate automagically in a ResultMap.

Are DB specific solutions an option?  For example, with PostgreSQL you can use common table expressions to select the data into a ResultSet that may be applicable to be mapped into a tree.

Otherwise you should just change your collection definition in the ResultMap to point to a query to select the children, which can reuse the same resultmap to get the recursive behavior

Comment: As I wrote in question, I don't want to use nested select, this could lead to hundreds of queries. I think the best idea is to select all nodes as flat list and use java to transform it to tree.